# cannot forward ref to component TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-forwardref

Trying to pass ref to my search component without any success. This is My component:

```
interface SearchInputProps {
  placeholder: string;
  onSearch: () => any;
}
// type TextInputProps = React.HTMLProps<TextInput>;

export const SearchInput: React.FC<SearchInputProps> = forwardRef<TextInput, SearchInputProps>(
  ({ placeholder, onSearch }, ref) => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", flex: 1, padding: 5 }}>
          <Ionicons name="search" color={Colors.white} size={23} />
          <TextInput
            autoFocus
            placeholder={placeholder}
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.lightGrey2}
            style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.weakGrey, flex: 1 }}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            value={searchText}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setSearchText(text);
              onSearch();
            }}
          ></TextInput>
          {searchText.length ? (
            <Ionicons
              name="close-circle"
              color={Colors.lightGrey}
              size={22}
              onPress={() => setSearchText("")}
              style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
);
```

creating the ref:

```
const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>();
```

The component:

```
<SearchInput placeholder={"Search a user"} onSearch={() => setIsTyping(true)} ref={inputRef} />
```

I get this error:

> Type '{ placeholder: string; onSearch: () => void; ref:
> MutableRefObject; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & SearchInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> SearchInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }

Answer (score 4):

```
export const SearchInput: React.FC<SearchInputProps> = forwardRef<TextInput, SearchInputProps>(
```

The problem is that you've added an explicit type annotation to `SearchInput` which overrides the type created by `forwardRef`.

`React.FC<SearchInputProps>` means that this component can only accept props from `SearchInputProps`.  It doesn't know anything about the `ref`.  The correct type for the `SearchInput` variable uses `ForwardRefExoticComponent` instead of `FC`.  It is:

```
React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<SearchInputProps & React.RefAttributes<TextInput>>
```

But I would recommend that you let the type of `SearchInput` be inferred rather than explicitly annotating it.  Simply delete the `: React.FC<SearchInputProps>` from your code and it will work.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLYBm0A7ilACbLXZFKtwC%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%20bh5GpaCOi4zqCENZ0ULASi8QjAABeDpwACYAMy8YZdnvdglQzG6s89lAGCBbNBEa83mMMyuZbK5R3vpCf5mDNGr4Wr%20-65FK86zjgkGLmsBalKEMAAOJiL0e6AcBPaJsmTpwCAjClF4AAyewwB6AAMNA1LK25IB6ABs2DTtABQwUudCoAA1ihSC9LWbpwO6EYvphVRAqkRoAPK1PgQIgGujp%20KkxAYaJFrOPm%20C7hOYRSqpakCjUZyhD0pRIFKjqNJQmg8l0OAiQZVQynKhJWYS2oOY5SRsuioQtBUXlVNw%20lqR0tzDFK0KngZOA6ZKhJwTcpQwKEcAAPymp5ol9gOQqEFljkjmOaAzsQdhoH6JVuAVBnMVAc5ZNAS7wYhPG9CFgXJJuO6Onu6E1WpNQxGChCWbZhRILKvlShqWodZ1tpJrueD4VAhE6CR1BkXAHbBQNN4nvtFqtAUOj4KkqTzT24XWnQ0XnsMt33VUHnRoBr1yHl8AABpKi07R2deX1wF4kRcNiHD4pFmJUmdF2vVUwMijMKiTGU2AylohCo2AZSKhDKrkJQjRKcQH3RgaRommaMb3L50IpOkH5Mt%20ODCOyKDKrkwi8D5EpjQDE3aNjaM6KUVlQFpzS8FyjqgwYrDHvdzRyNwQA)